# JWT Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

please take this doubt away.

I have a Spring Boot application with spring security using JWT.

One question I always had is: How does Spring store the generated tokens?

Looking at the manager of my tomcat, I saw that this application has some open sessions, but it works exclusively with JWT. There is no point in it where I request to open a session.

So can I assume that Spring creates sessions to store the generated tokens?

Comment: Spring does not store the JWT tokens. What your JWT library does is to verify if the incoming token is valid and active. This validation is done based on the secret provided and also based on the lifetime of the token.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.

So what happens is that when spring security receives a token it just calculates if that is a valid token based on the expiration date?

And could you tell me the reason for the open tomcat sessions?

Comment: Usually for token based authentication you as a developer specify explicitly what happens when a new token is received, in most cases the token gets decrypted and the expiration dates are verified. Spring Security by default has the session creation policy set to IF_REQUIRED, which means you get a session cookie created automatically. Since you are using JWT, you should set the session creation policy to STATELESS, which means you should not have the session cookie created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you authenticate and then get issued a token from an issuer.

When this token is presented to a spring server, the resource server needs to do multiple validations before it will let you use the api.

A JWT is not encrypted, it is `encoded`, which means, everyone can see and read its contents. But it is also `signed`, so that you can not tamper with its contents without breaking the signage.

So the first thing a server does is to verify the signature to be sure it hasn't been temepered with. This can be done in multiple ways, one is to take the token and send it to the issuer and basically ask "hello is this token valid?" and the issuer says "YAY" or "NEY".

This generates a lot of extra network traffic if it needs to send jwts back and fourth for validation.

Since the signage of tokens are done with asymmetric encryption, the resource server can periodically (for instance each 30 mins) ask the issuer for the public key so it can verify the tokens itself without constantly needing to ask if they are valid or not.

This key is usually sent in a format called JWK (Json web key) and this key is then used to validate the integrity. If this validation passes it can trust the jwts content, and start checking the validation date, the scopes, and any extra claims in it etc.

And then if the token is valid has not expired, you can for instance choose to construct a UserDetails object from the data in the jwt.

As mentioned in the comments. If using JWTs you have no need for a session.
you should disable session creation.

You can read a lot more about sessions in this article here [Spring Security Session](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)

And here you can read about spring security [Session Managment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#session-mgmt)